# Express: Connect do different Mongo tables when hitting from different subdomain

Tags: webserver, subdomain, hosting

I'm not sure how exactly to phrase this question the best. It was quite hard to find a specific answer. I'm a beginner in Node and Mongo and I need to handle this task.

The collections:

- There are collections called `Ingredients`, which are available to everyone
- There are collections called `Recipes` which are made by users by combining Ingredients

Now what I want is to create subdomains like such: `communityone.domain.com`, `communitytwo.domain.com`

What I want to do is make the Ingredients collection available to all subdomains, but make the Recipes local to the respective subdomain. So that means only communityone can view the Recipes made by users on `communityone.domain.com`, and likewise for `community two`

What is the way to do this? I'm completely lost on where to start. If it's any relevant (familiar), I'm using React and Redux, and probably Mongoose as well (new to me).

Comment: one question I want to know is whether this would involve the Redux/React side at all or it's all figured out by Express

Comment: I'm not sure how the question relates to any of the technologies you list. If all you are talking about is *"different website addresses"* then this really has nothing to do with the database, implementation language or really anything in the stack at all. Domain names really just point to a server and the application there sorts it out. If the domain matters, then you segment data based on the supplied address. But this really seems way too broad, and it's pretty unclear what you are actually asking anyway.